# Yii framework SMTP mail with gmail from email id not changed

Tags: php, email, yii, phpmailer

I am using this extension.
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/smtp-mail

I would work properly. But From Email id in mail not set that i have defined in **"SetFrom()"** function but it takes Gmail username (myemail@gmail.com).

Below is my code for sending mail in my Controller.

```
 $mail = Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
 $mail->SetFrom("otherid",$from_name); // This id not coming in  my response mail
 $mail->Subject = $subject;
 $mail->MsgHTML($message);
 $mail->AddAddress($to, "");
```

config/main.php

```
'Smtpmail'=>array(
            'class'     => 'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
            'Host'      => "smtp.gmail.com",
            'Username'  => 'myemail@gmail.com',
            'Password'  => 'password',
            'Mailer'    => 'smtp',
            'Port'      => 465,
            'SMTPAuth'  => true,
            'SMTPSecure' => 'ssl'
        ),
```

Comment: What are the exact values you are setting for the `$mail` object? `"otherid"` is actually some email id right?

Comment: $mail object first load my extension class. and then assign the to, from , from name and msg.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail doesn't seem to allow sending the email via a different email-id if its not registered to the primary gmail account.

1. When logged in to the `primary gmail account` -> go to `Account` tab (top-right).
2. Search for `Add another email address` under `Send mail as`.

   Add the new email address there. Confirm the link sent to the additional email account.
3. On confirmation, your account can send emails from either of the address.

Try the new email address now in `$mail->SetFrom("new_gmail_id@gmail.com", $from_name);` and it will work fine.

I have tried that and it works. Let us know if you have done all this already.